# There is not showing the grid view in the blog section of betheme of Wordpresss

Tags: c#, wordpress, reactjs

I am using the betheme for designing my site. I want the post show in Grid View layout but there is no grid view. How can I add the grid view manually.[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rhbd6.jpg)

Answer (score 0):

BeTheme uses WPBakery, not Visual Composer. You need to have the last version 5.7 and then just add the Post Grid element using the editor.
More information, contact BeTheme support or support.wpbakery.com if you have a valid license.

Answer (score -1):

Grid View layout is supported by visual composer in be theme please find it and use it in your page through shortcode

Comment: how i can use it?

Comment: visual composer(in latest version its wp bakery ) plugin is builtin plugin in the be theme just install visual composer .after installation , go to all pages an option will appear infront of all the pages like 'edit with visual composer' . edit the page with visual composer and add the grid layout component for posts in the page. if you need futher clearance let me know as i send you screenshots of it